# Is keycloak destroy user session if browser closes but not log out?

Tags: keycloak

I am new to keycloak. When I log in my application and close the browser. I can still see my user session is active when I did not enable 'remember me'. Is this expected? From my understanding, the keycloak should remove the session when the user closes the browser except remember me is checked. Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Keycloak gives you fine grain control of session, cookie, and token timeouts, you can find more details in the documentation

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_timeouts